# When executing this code, instead of moving all items from 'myList' to 'myCart' it's exiting after moving just 3 of the items. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, foreach

```
let myList = ['pop tarts', 'ramen', 'chips', 'salsa', 'coffee']
let myCart = []


myList.forEach((item) => {
let poppedItem = myList.pop()
myCart.push(poppedItem)
console.log(myList)
console.log(myCart)
})
```

// When executing this code, instead of moving all items from 'myList' to 'myCart' it's exiting after moving just 3 of the items. I am totally lost as to why-

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let myList = ['pop tarts', 'ramen', 'chips', 'salsa', 'coffee']
let myCart = Array.from(myList);
myList  = []
console.log(myList)
console.log(myCart)
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is expected because you are iterating over the array and in the same time you are modifying it.

- Step 0 : item = 'pop tarts', 'coffee' is removed, myList = ['pop
  tarts', 'ramen', 'chips', 'salsa']
- Step 1 : item = 'ramen', 'salsa' is removed, myList = ['pop tarts', 'ramen', 'chips']
- Step 2 : item = 'chips', 'chips' is removed, myList = ['pop tarts', 'ramen']

You are already visited all the elements of the array so the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?retiredLocale=it) ends, for further informations you can check the mozilla documentation link I provided containing the [modifying_the_array_during_iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?retiredLocale=it#modifying_the_array_during_iteration) paragraph.